# How to configure Jersey (javax.ws.rs.*) to reuse ssl sessions

Tags: java, ssl, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, keep-alive

I have written a test client that sends requests over TLS using the Jersey library. I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to configure/code the Jersey client such that it reuses the SSL sessions so that I could make my tests faster. The Jersey client by default uses HTTP keepAlive; meaning it keeps the TCP connections open and reuses them, but it doesn't seem to do the same with SSL sessions.

If anyone had any experience with this, please let me know.

Here is the code snippet with which I am setting up the Jersey Client and also the code with which I am sending a request:

```
        SSLContext sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext().getInstance(tlsVersion);
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine("qa.p.uvvu.com", 7001);

        Client client =  ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext)
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).build();


    response = client.target(uri).request()
            .headers(multivaluedMap).post(Entity.entity(object, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));
```

Comment: TLS session reuse is the default at the JSSE level, and indeed I'm not aware of a way to configure it off. What makes you think it isn't happening? And if it isn't, what makes you think it's the client end that's responsible? I would have a good look at the *server* configuration.

Comment: Thanks EJP for taking the time and replying.. I was sure that the server side settings were right and was looking at the sessionIDs on the server side during my test changing for every request. So, was sure. Finally, changing to GrizzlyConnectorProvider has solved the issue and now my tests are faster by almost thrice! Thanks!

Comment: But does that happen when you use a browser for the client?

Comment: @Naren Nala can you provide your solution i am also trying the same but unable to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Apache connector for this:

```
HttpClientConnectionManager connManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connManager);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

You can configure the [HttpClientConnectionManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) to your needs depending on how many connections you want to keep in the pool, and for how long you want to keep them in the pool.

Disclaimer: I don't have the code with me, so the code above might not work 100%.

Comment: Nothing to do with TLS sessions.

Comment: Thanks Augusto! I tried to use the ApacheConnectorProvider as you suggested and it seems to throw up since I am using self signed certs. But, I researched a little bit and used GrizzlyConnectorProvider and that solved the issue. Thanks a bunch again for helping me with this.

Comment: @NarenNala So in what way is this a correct answer?

Comment: By reusing the connections with the connection pool, you don't need to re-stablish the TLS session on each call, as the connection is kept open (the Apache http client ensures this). So you end up avoiding the expensive TLS handshake. @EJP, you sound like you know this stuff, can you explain your other solution?

Comment: @Augusto What other solution?

Comment: @user207421  using GrizzlyConnectorProvider  he wrote in the comment(very clearly) that solved the TLS issue, and if he didn't have self-signing certs. ApacheConnetorProvider would have worked!   upvoted.